# Using my with parentheses and only one variable

Tags: perl

I sometimes see Perl code like this:

```
my ( $variable ) = blah....
```

What is the point of putting parentheses around a single variable?  I thought parentheses were only used when declaring multiple variables, like:

```
my ( $var1, $var2, $var3 ) = blah...
```

Comment: it might be helpful for maintenance, if it is apparent that a list might be the future expectation. I normally use it while reading subroutine arguments, like `my ($arg1) = @_` rather than `my $arg1 = shift`

Comment: I'm just used to typing `m y (`. And, a list of one item is still a list. :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are several scenarios when there is a difference:

1. When **array** is on right side

   ```
   my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');
   my  $variable  = @array;           #  3   size of @array
   my ($variable) = @array;           # 'a'  $array[0]
   ```
2. When **list** is on right side

   ```
   my  $variable  = qw/ a b c d /;    # 'd'  last  item of the list
   my ($variable) = qw/ a b c d /;    # 'a'  first item of the list
   ```
3. Subroutine with variable (**array/scalar**) return value

   ```
   sub myFunction {
     ...
     return (wantarray() ? @array : $scalar);
   }
   my  $variable  = myFunction(...);  # $scalar   from the subroutine
   my ($variable) = myFunction(...);  # $array[0] from the subroutine
   ```

Answer (score 21):

The parentheses create a list context which affects how the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated.

Compare

```
my $x = grep { /s/ } qw(apples bananas cherries);
print $x;
```

with

```
my ($x) = grep { /s/ } qw(apples bananas cherries);
print $x;
```

You will often use this construction when [you just want to grab the first element of a list and discard the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728337/).

Comment: Technically, it affects how both sides of the assignment operator is evaluated (by changing which assignment operator is used).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a Perl pro (by all means, I'm not), but AFAIK it has to do with lists.
Perl has different contexts (scalar, list). Using `($var)` switches to list context, `$var` is scalar context.

```
my $var = (1, 2, 4);   # $var = 4 (last element)
my ($var) = (1, 2, 4); # $var = 1
```

Comment: You're right, and `$var = grep {; defined } (1, 2, 4);` = 3 (items)

Comment: Also `my @a = (1,2,4); my $v = @a; print $v;` = 3

Comment: However `$var = (1, 2, 4)` assigns 4 to `$var`. `grep` behaves in a specific way depending on its context, and in scalar context it provides the number of list elements that pass the test. That is different from the behaviour of a list in scalar context.

Comment: @Borodin: yes, like I wrote in my answer

Comment: No not like you wrote in your answer. In scalar context `(1,2,4)` is not a list but an expression with the comma operator that returns it's right hand side and discards it's left hand side. Resulting in 4 being returned

Comment: @mugenkenichi: »However $var = (1, 2, 4) assigns 4 to $var.« … I have written the same statement in my answer. Yes, I have explained it has to do with lists, but the code is the same. (I will update my answer now)

Comment: It might seem picky but it is just not a good example to show what you mean.. it has to with context not with lists. It is a tricky one though. Your first comment is a good example.

Comment: This could be of help understanding why `my $var = (1,2,4)` is not a good example.. there is no list nor list context in this line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042436/and-operators-in-perl/5043214#5043214

Comment: [perlfaq4: What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f)

Comment: ***FYI*** `my @array = (1,2,4); my $var = @array` will result in `$var` containing `3`, which is the number of elements in the array. ( `my $var = @{[1,2,4]}` does the same thing ) Whereas `my ($var) = @array` will result in `$var` containing the first element of `@array`.

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing two different things. First off, when using `my` to declare several variables, you need to use parentheses:

```
my $foo, $bar;
```

Does not work, as it is considered to be two different statements:

```
my $foo;
$bar;
```

So you need parentheses to group together the argument into an argument list to the *function* `my`:

```
my($foo, $bar);
```

Secondly, you have explicit grouping in order to invoke list context:

```
$foo, $bar = "a", "b"; # wrong!
```

Will be considered three separate statements:

```
$foo;
$bar = "a";
"b";
```

But if you use parentheses to group `$foo` and `$bar` into a list, the assignment operator will use a list context:

```
($foo, $bar) = ("a", "b");
```

Curiously, if you remove the RHS parentheses, you will also experience a hickup:

```
($foo, $bar) = "a", "b"; # Useless use of a constant (b) in void context
```

But that is because the `=` operator has higher precedence than comma `,`, which you can see in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). If you try:

```
my @array = ("a", "b");
($foo, $bar) = @array;
```

You will get the desired behaviour without parentheses.

Now to complete the circle, lets remove the list context in the above and see what happens:

```
my @array = ("a", "b");
$foo = @array;
print $foo;
```

This prints `2`, because the array is evaluated in scalar context, and arrays in scalar context return the number of elements they contain. In this case, it is `2`.

Hence, statements such as these use list context:

```
my ($foo) = @array;          # $foo is set to $array[0], first array element
my ($bar) = ("a", "b", "c"); # $bar is set to "a", first list element
```

It is a way of overriding the scalar context which is implied in scalar assignment. For comparison, these assignments are in scalar context:

```
my $foo = @array;            # $foo is set to the number of elements in the array
my $bar = ("a", "b", "c");   # $bar is set to "c", last list element
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `my $foo = ("a", "b"); print $foo;` will print `b`, and not `2`

Comment: @knittl Not as interesting as it sounds, because only *arrays* have that behaviour, not lists. In scalar context, lists return their last element instead.

Comment: [perlfaq4: What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f)

Comment: There's really no such thing as a list in scalar context. There's just scalars separated by the scalar version of the comma operator. It's as much a list as `$a && $b && $c`.

Comment: @brian d foy, `$x=(4,5,6);` has a list in scalar context. Notice the "s" that follows "list" in `perl -MO=Concise -e'$x=(4,5,6);'` The list/comma operator is not a binary operator like `&&`.

Comment: From perlfunc: "You can't get a list like (1,2,3) into being in scalar context, because the compiler knows the context at compile time. It would generate the scalar comma operator there, not the list construction version of the comma. That means it was never a list to start with."

Comment: This answer doesn't show why you would use `my ($var) = @array;` instead of `my $var = @array;`. ( Which was the whole point of the question. )

Comment: @brian d foy, That simply says that lists (value) can't be *returned* in scalar context. A list (operator) can still exist in scalar context, though. As for "scalar comma operator", it's just another name for "comma operator", which is just another name for the "list operator". Did you run the code I gave you? What Perl actually does trumps any docs that say otherwise

Comment: @BradGilbert I explicitly explain the difference between using list and scalar context when using an array in the RHS. I don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: You didn't put `my ($foo)` anywhere in your answer. That is what the question was about. It is a way of getting only the [first element of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3728386) while also defining a variable.

Comment: @BradGilbert Well, I explain the basic concepts. What you are referring to, and the specific question are only extensions of those basic concepts.

Comment: @BradGilbert I have updated with a conclusion, is this what you meant?

Comment: ***+1*** ... The only thing I would consider adding, is that it causes a subroutine to be called in list context.

Comment: @BradGilbert That would be another extension of a basic concept. You have to draw the line somewhere, my answer is already very long.

Comment: Your answer is short in comparison to some of my most up-voted answers. ( I didn't say I would add it, only that I would have *considered* adding it )

Answer (score 2):

[*This answer is also found in table format [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).*]

The symbol `=` is compiled into one of two assignment operators:

- A *list assignment operator* (`aassign`) is used if the left-hand side (LHS) of a `=` is some kind of aggregate.
- A *scalar assignment operator* (`sassign`)  is used otherwise.

The following are considered to be aggregates:

- Any expression in parentheses (e.g. `(...)`)
- An array (e.g. `@array`)
- An array slice (e.g. `@array[...]`)
- A hash (e.g. `%hash`)
- A hash slice (e.g. `@hash{...}`)
- Any of the above preceded by `my`, `our` or `local`

There are two differences between the operators.

### Context of Operands

The two operators differ in the context in which their operands are evaluated.

- The scalar assignment evaluates both of its operands in scalar context.

  ```
    # @array evaluated in scalar context.
    my $count = @array;
  ```
- The list assignment evaluates both of its operands in list context.

  ```
    # @array evaluated in list context.
    my @copy = @array;
  ```

  ```
    # @array evaluated in list context.
    my ($first) = @array;
  ```

### Value(s) Returned

The two operators differ in what they return.

- The scalar assignment ...

  - ... in scalar context evaluates to its LHS as an lvalue.

    ```
      # The s/// operates on $copy.
      (my $copy = $str) =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
    ```
  - ... in list context evaluates to its LHS as an lvalue.

    ```
      # Prints $x.
      print($x = $y);
    ```
- The list assignment ...

  - ... in scalar context evaluates to the number of scalars returned by its RHS.

    ```
      # Only dies if f() returns an empty list.
      # This does not die if f() returns a
      # false scalar like zero or undef.
      my ($x) = f() or die;
    ```

    ```
      # $counts gets the number of scalars returns by f().
      my $count = () = f();
    ```
  - ... in list context evaluates to the scalars returned by its LHS as lvalues.

    ```
      # Prints @x.
      print(@x = @y);
    ```

Comment: Apparently someone does have a problem with offsite linking to documentation. I usually recommend to add a summary to your answer.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, Repeating what was already said 4 times is not a good thing as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: If you look at all of the link-only answers on StackOverflow ( including deleted ones ) you'll find that a significant number of them are dead links. If your link pointed somewhere that hasn't been around as long as long as [Perl Monks](http://perlmonks.org), I would probably have down-voted it as well. Also there are several ways to get around the lack of tables.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, Yes, but I did link to a site that has been around as long as PerlMonks.

Comment: I was pointing out that [*Link-Only* answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=link+only) are [**very much discouraged**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, You should read your own link. (Is that a subtle point? If so, I don't see how it applies.) I did not provide directions towards the answer, I provide directions to the answer; the OP knew exactly what he was clicking into; and Bitrot is not a factor. Furthermore, that very post argues that I should have linked. (SO should be treated like email, it argues, and there's no way a complex HTML page should be sent in an email.)

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I asked the question because the downvotes were downright hypocritical. The "exact duplicate" links posted here a gazillion times a day are the real violatiors of acceptability. Not only are the linked pages not even close to being "exact duplicates", they are frequently not even in the same ballpark. Combined with the resulting question closure, the petitioner is left without an answer. In this case, the OP go a clear, good answer that he could not have gotten otherwise due to SO limitations.

Comment: I don't see how down-votes on this answer can be hypocritical, unless you are certain that the people who down-voted have posted answers that are link-only answers, and that is the only reason they down-voted. ... As for exact duplicates, edit them to differentiate them, and vote to open. Most of the questions that were incorrectly closed as "*Exact Duplicate*", should still have been closed, but for other reasons. If you really have a problem with how the site is run, you should be active on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I said downvoting a great answer because it's accessible through a link while closing nodes to replace them with a link to a useless "answer" is hyprocitical. And how can I edit a node to differentiate it when it's already different?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33071491)

Comment: @PeterJ, The answer was added to this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924) long ago, but it's not nearly as readable. I have replaced the text of my answer with the text of that answer. Now *this* is the answer that might become out of date.