# Dereferencing hash reference passed to a subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm working through some sample code, and I'm trying to figure out why it works with the brackets around $args. Without it, I don't get the values.

```
sub random_dice{
  my ($args) = @_;
  my $number_of_rolls = $args->{number_of_rolls} || 6;
  ...
}

# I don't understand why it works with the brackets around $args
my $r = random_dice({number_of_rolls=>5});
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031455/perl-using-my-with-parentheses-and-only-one-variable

Comment: read the tutorial on references: [perldoc perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works because you are passing an anonymous hash to your random_dice subroutine.

```
my ($args) = @_; # sets $args as element of @_. Not as an array
```

$args is now a reference to a hash

```
$args = {
   number_of_rolls => 5
};
```

This is generally used as a method to have named parameters in Perl

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
my $args = @_;
```

the assignment is made in **scalar context**, so $args is assigned the value 1 (the number of elements in the array).

But like this:

```
my ($args) = @_;
```

the assignment is made in **list context**.  The values from the array on the right side are unpacked and assigned to elements of the array on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the simpler

```
my $r = random_dice( number_of_rolls => 5 );
```

the sub would have to be changed to

```
sub random_dice{
  my %args = @_;
  my $number_of_rolls = $args{number_of_rolls} || 6;
  ...
}
```