# Is my ($ptBatchRec); a pointer?

Tags: perl

I have looked at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031455/perl-using-my-with-parentheses-and-only-one-variable), and saw the part about

```
my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my  $variable  = @array;           #  3   size of @array
my ($variable) = @array;           # 'a'  $array[0]
```

assigning the first element of `@array` to `my ($variable)`.

I am a little confused about the following code that I have inherited. Specifically, is

`my ($ptBatchRec);`

being declared as a pointer?

What would happen if I removed the parentheses?

```
my $DBHandle = shift;                   # The ICS database handle
my $ptBatchStruct = shift;              # -> batch structure (hash)
my ($FiscalYear, $AccountType, $BatchType, $PaymentType, %Args) = @_;

my $DBIsLocked = 0;                     # Database is locked flag
my ($ptBatchRec);                       # -> batch record
.
.
.
    $ptBatchRec = $DBHandle->selectrow_hashref(
        "select * from batch " .
            "where yr matches ".$DBHandle->quote($FiscalYear)." " .
                "and entry_date = " .
                    $DBHandle->quote($ptBatchStruct->{"entry_date"})." " .
                "and acct_type = ".$DBHandle->quote($AccountType)." " .
                "and batch_type = ".$DBHandle->quote($BatchType)." " .
                "and pymt_code = ".$DBHandle->quote($PaymentType)." " .
            "order by batch_num desc");
```

Comment: Legibility would benefit from query placeholders:  `$db->selectrow_hashref("select * from batch where yr matches ? and entry_date = ? ...", undef, $FiscalYear, $ptB->{entry_date}, ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not being declared as anything in particular (it's a scalar, from the `$`, and it doesn't get initialized so it will start out holding `undef`).

Then it's assigned the result of `selectrow_hashref`, which you can tell from the name, will return a hash reference (at least if it's successful; it could be `undef` on failure). A reference is a little bit like a pointer, but there are no "pointers" in perl. [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref) and [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut) are good resources here.

In particular, using parentheses does not change the declaration.

Comment: As I've edited the OP to reflect, what would happen if the parentheses were removed?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, nothing. The parens don't do anything there.

Answer (score 3):

1. Perl has no pointers. They are called *references* (but are exactly like pointers minus pointer arithmetic).
2. The parens are no special syntax. Here, they just supply *list context* for RHS of the assignment. I.e.

   ```
   my ($x, $y) = @array;
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   (my $x, my $y) = ($array[0], $array[1]);
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   my $x = $array[0]; my $y = $array[1];
   ```

   Thus the special case of one element on the LHS `my ($x) = @array` is the same as

   ```
   my $x = $array[0];
   ```

   If parens are used for `my`, but no values are assigned, then this is only useful to declare multiple variables, so `my ($foo);` and `my $foo;` are exactly equivalent.
3. The `$DBHandle->selectrow_hashref` aims to return a reference to a hash. When this is assigned to the `$ptBatchRec` variable, yes, that variable will hold a reference.

   But that variable can hold any type of scalar, of which hash references are just one type.